# Which layout manager to use for a nested table layout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I am looking for some guidance on how to achieve a certain Swing layout.

What I am looking to achieve is at the beginning have a layout with two rows. On a user command I would like the second row to split into several columns, and for each of these column cells to recursively split as above.

E.g. at the beginning:

```
 -------------------
| Some stuff here   |
 -------------------
|                   |
 -------------------
```

Becomes:

```
 -------------------
| Some stuff here   |
 -------------------
|  stuff  | stuff   |
|---------|---------|
|         |         |
 -------------------
```

etc.

Comment: Where is you code.? Provide something so we can comment on that and help you build the desired result.

Comment: I'm looking for help on this design decision before I start coding

Comment: If you're asking a design question, it might help to give us more background on why you want to do this.  Maybe there's a better way to accomplish what you want without splitting columns...

Comment: +1 to Nick Rippe. I can see at least 4 or 5 different ways to perform what you are exposing but having more information could rule out some of them. Are the columns below suitable to be put in a JTable?

Answer (score 3):

I would have said GridBagLayout, as it gives you exactly what you want without having to combine different layout managers within panels etc

Also refer to [Java Visual Guide to LayoutManagers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: But can GridBagLayout cells be split into further columns? If not won't this make it difficult to calculate dynamically the positions of elements

Comment: I would rather have something that can spit and automtically fill the space it can

Comment: `GridGagLayout` will allow to specify the `fill`, `weight` and `gridwidth` (span).  I suggest you take a look at [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information